# how to send multiple log files to amazon cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a monolith that is currently being transferred to aws (using ecs/fargate), and will later be broken up into microservices. It uses an amazon linux 1 image provisioned with apache, php, and all of my production website data. Currently, it sends logs to several files in /etc/httpd/logs and /var/www/vhosts/logs.

supposedly there's some stuff I can do in ecs task Definitions with log configurations and volumes, but I haven't been able to find anything that explains the details on how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a container, I will never suggest writing logs to file, better to write logs container stdout and stderr.

Another interesting thing,  how you will deal with logfile if you moved to fargate? so do not write logs to file and do not treat the container like instance machine.

The beauty of AWS log driver is, it pushes to logs to Cloud watch logs and from cloud watch it also super easy to push these to ELK.

Go for AWS log driver, design your **entrypoint** in way that it writes logs to stdout and stderr in the container. normally this is super easy when you run the process in the foreground it automatically writes log to container stdout.

Just add this line in your task definition and add cloud watch role.

```
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-wordpress",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-example"
                }
            }
```

or 
[image]

once it configured you will see the logs

[image]

**Using the awslogs Log Driver**

> You can configure the containers in your tasks to send log information
>   to CloudWatch Logs. If you are using the Fargate launch type for your
>   tasks, this allows you to view the logs from your containers. If you
>   are using the EC2 launch type, this enables you to view different logs
>   from your containers in one convenient location, and it prevents your
>   container logs from taking up disk space on your container instances.
>   This topic helps you get started using the awslogs log driver in your
>   task definitions.

**Note**

> The type of information that is logged by the containers in your task
>   depends mostly on their `ENTRYPOINT command`. By default, the logs that
>   are captured show the command output that you would normally see in an
>   interactive terminal if you ran the container locally, which are the
>   `STDOUT` and `STDERR I/O streams`. **The awslogs log driver simply passes
>   these logs from Docker to CloudWatch Logs.** For more information on how
>   Docker logs are processed, including alternative ways to capture
>   different file data or streams, see View logs for a container or
>   service in the Docker documentation.

[image]
[aws-ecs-log-driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Comment: interesting. So redirecting log files to to stdout/stderr isn't just the default solution, but the recommended one? Now that I think about it, I suppose it really doesn't matter where you store the files in the container (if at all), since all that stuff should be stored outside the container anyways. and once the monolith is broken up into microservices, I probably won't need multiple file locations for logs.

Comment: Exactly in mirco services you've one process per container so you'll have one file per container

Comment: How is this helpful if you have an application which has, for example, 3 different log files of entirely different category that should be streamed to different cloudwatch log groups?

Comment: to support multiple log groups, create additional containers which can read the log files, stream the contents to docker log, and then bind the aws log drive for that container to your specific log group